# test Rest API with nodejs, mocha and grunt in one command

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, mocha.js, nodemon

I found this very helpful tutorial on how to test Rest APIs with nodejs: http://thewayofcode.wordpress.com/2013/04/21/how-to-build-and-test-rest-api-with-nodejs-express-mocha/

I'm just still looking for a way to run a 'test' server with a 'test' DB 
(that gets emptied on testing start every time)

currently my grunt js setup is something like this:

```
//...
concurrent: {
  nodemon_test: {
    options: {
      logConcurrentOutput: true,
    },
    tasks: [
      'nodemon:dev',
      'mochaTest'
    ]
  },
},
nodemon: {
  test: {
    options: {
      file: 'server.js',
      args: ['test'],
      watchedExtensions: ['js'],
      watchedFolders: ['server'],
      debug: false,
      delayTime: 2,
      env: {
        NODE_ENV: 'test'
      },
      cwd: __dirname
    }
  }
}
//...
grunt.registerTask('test', [
  'concurrent:nodemon_test',
]);
```

but since I can't figure out how to wait until the server is running and connected to the DB